# Facebook Login JS SDK - getLoginStatus always return unknown

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

Always when I try to log in with Facebook, using the JavaScript SDK, and want to get the log in status I receive a response with 'unknown'. I read all Facebook's documentation and a lot post and I still having the same error.

I'm using Google Chrome Versión 61.

This is my code:

```
(function(d, s, id){
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.com/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
      appId      : appID,
      xfbml      : true, // parse XFBML
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      version    : 'v2.10'
   });

   FB.AppEvents.logPageView();

   // Get current login url
   var url = new URL(window.location.href);
   // Get if the user has been connected via Facebook
   var conn = url.searchParams.get("connected");
   // Check the var
   if(conn == "true" || conn == true){
     loginWithFacebook(null);
   }
};

// Login with Facebook
function loginWithFacebook(elementButton){  
  // Javascript URL    
  var strUri = encodeURI('https://vinglet.com/login?connected=true'),
      myPermissionLogIN = 'email,public_profile';
  // Check if the user has initialized session on the app
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      // Check the status of the user
      if (response.status !== 'connected'){
      window.location.href = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id='+appID+'&scope='+myPermissionLogIN+'&redirect_uri='+strUri;
   }
   else{
      var meObject = {
          fields: `first_name, last_name, email, public_key, 
            middle_name, link, gender, birthday, about`
      };
      // Save the data into the DB
      loginWithFacebookAJAX(meObject,elementButton);
   }
  });    
}
```

Comment: why not use FB.login? this is some weird code...

Comment: take a look at this and read all the text: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: @luschn because FB.login opens a popup and Chrome blocks it, the only way, that I found, to open the login dialog in a new tab is with this method

Comment: read the article carefully, i am pretty sure you are doing it wrong, trying to call FB.login in the asynchronous callback of FB.getLoginStatus. of course browser block the popup then, because you don´t call it on user interaction, as intended.

Comment: @luschn I'm reading it now and then I'm going to update all my code. Thank you very much for your help Luschn